# How to stop background image from losing quality/ blurring on screen resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

When I was creating a website I noticed that my background was blurred because of the screen size
I want that to stop so I can be happier with my website and visitors will be better. Also, my background looks fine on the original image size of the bg. Here is my code and the code pen.

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/6750263_preview.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Shop</a>
    <a href="#">My Projects</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

https://codepen.io/Javscript/pen/XWMwNYN?editors=1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can media queries in your CSS to load a larger image as appropriate to the users screen size.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("/image.png");
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("/image-small.png");
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("/image-medium.png");
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("/image-large.png");
  }
}
```

You will need to host the image in multiple sizes for this to work.

You can read more about media queries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: But, how do I make smaller images any image dowsizers?

Comment: @Jason You can use an image editing software like Photoshop, or google for "image resizer online"

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Jason Your original image resolution is already low, what are you gonna do after downsizing it. you need a  higher resolution image with increasing screen size, So just use higher resolution image and decrease their resolution with smaller screen size only if needed.